# Export gridview to any format

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

I am trying to export gridview to excel / pdf / word format

I have added all necessary implementation but still it gives me an error like "control of type 'gridview' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server"

Please look at my code below ,

**.aspx page**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/OrganizationMaster.Master" EnableEventValidation="false" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SearchInvoice.aspx.cs" Inherits="Site.pages.ContactStaff.ViewInvoice" %>
```

**.aspx.cs page**

```
  public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
           server control at run time. */
    }
```

**.ascx.cs control**

```
 protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlExport.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
              if (ddlExport.SelectedValue == "Word")
            {
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=OtherCourses.doc");
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.word";

                StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
                List<InvoiceHelper> invoicelist = svc.RetriveInvoiceList(Request.Url);
                grdinvoicelist.AllowPaging = false;
                grdinvoicelist.DataSource = invoicelist;
                grdinvoicelist.DataBind();
                grdinvoicelist.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

                Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what about the design page?

Comment: R u talking about .ascx page ?

Comment: .aspx because you have used master page too. may be there could be any conflict at the <asp:content> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You might have same problem as I had.

Inside your MasterPage you already have a form tag,
When you do 2nd form tag in your webform.

try using cleanest masterpage as possible such as:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TotalEmpty.master.cs" 

Inherits="ProjectName.MasterPages.TotalEmpty" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using only one form tag inside the control. (Not in the master page or the web page calling the control)